# Hitch installation completed with insserv errors. Unable to start hitch

Tags: varnish

I am trying to install hitch to terminate the certificates for the Varnish reverse proxy on my Ubuntu 16.04 VPS. The installation completes with the following messages and Hitch service doesnt startup.

```
sridhar@SastraTechnologies:~$ sudo apt install hitch
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  libuv1
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  hitch
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 100 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/51.1 kB of archives.
After this operation, 163 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Selecting previously unselected package hitch.
(Reading database ... 249839 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../hitch_1.1.1-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking hitch (1.1.1-1) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (229-4ubuntu21.27) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-19.1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Setting up hitch (1.1.1-1) ...
insserv: Script nagios is broken: incomplete LSB comment.
insserv: missing `Default-Start:'  entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: missing `Default-Stop:'   entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: Default-Start undefined, assuming empty start runlevel(s) for script `nagios'
insserv: Default-Stop  undefined, assuming empty stop  runlevel(s) for script `nagios'
```

Tried removing the packahe updating the repository and installing it again but the results are the same. Is there anything that I can do to resolve the insserv messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you're better off using the official packages instead. You can find them on https://packagecloud.io/varnishcache/hitch.

These packages are maintained by Varnish Software, contain a more recent version of Hitch, and are regularly updated.

There are Ubuntu packages available for 16.04, or more recent versions.

The following commands will get the job done:

```
$ curl -s https://packagecloud.io/install/repositories/varnishcache/hitch/script.deb.sh | sudo bash
$ sudo apt install -y hitch
```

Comment: Was able to sucessfully install hitch. Thank you.